# Calling window.addEventListener("online") getting fired multiple times from a LWC within salesforce1 app

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, salesforce1-app

I have a LWC component which captures online and offline events and make's apex call accordingly.
I have used window object's online eventListener to capture the online event.

After event is fired a apex insert call is made.
But the insert function is called multiple time's and many records are created.

I did referred below link but it didn't helped
[Lightning Component - AddEventListener firing multiple times](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271972/lightning-component-addeventlistener-firing-multiple-times)

Pseudo code for reference:

```
    whenOnlineDoThis = () => {
        //Apex insert call
    }

    whenOfflineDoThis = () => {
        // Some UI changes
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        window.addEventListener('online',this.whenOnlineDoThis);
        window.addEventListener('offline',this.whenOfflineDoThis);
    }

    disconnectedCallback(){
        window.removeEventListener('online',this.whenOnlineDoThis);
        window.removeEventListener('offline',this.whenOfflineDoThis);
    }
```

Note: This is mostly observed when user has used pull to refresh when he was offline. So is it the case that, event listener is getting re-register with every pull to refresh?

Answer (score 0):

this happens when you invoke the function as you are doing:

```
window.addEventListener('online', this.functionName)
```

instead of passing it for it to be triggered when the event actually occurs:

```
window.addEventListener('online', (e) => {this.functionName(e)});
```

Comment: I referred this link https://www.programmersought.com/article/70303905152/